# How to track clicks from the current tab to a new one?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need some help.

I need to track clicks from the current tab to a new one when I click on any menu item, and then pull up the current user's cookies on a new tab. Now it pulls up the latest user from localStorage.

Can you direct me in the right direction? I try to understand the algorithm of actions.

I think I need to work with currentTabId in onBeforeSendHeaders. Am I right?

It's my code https://jsbin.com/cetezesami/edit?html,css,js,output

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: In my popup.js I try to get an array of all tabs with `chrome.tabs.query` method, but in **object queryInfo** I put `chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}` and get an array with one element - active tab. If I remove `active: true` I get what I want, an array of all tabs, but my code in background.js breaks down (here I try to get the collection which contains pairs tabId:value, userVal:value), when user click the link with User1, the object must be created and pushed to array (collection). Now it works.

Comment: But if I remove `active: true` from `chrome.tabs.query` - the second user's click by link User2 doesn't add object to my collection.

Comment: Here the part of my code in bg.js https://jsbin.com/cetezesami/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: What can I do in such situation?

Comment: This is my algorithm of actions: 1.Get all tabs which opened with same domain.  2.Compare this tab's id with tab's id from my collection, if such tab's id doesn't exist (it means that a new tab is opened), I save it.  3.And then I want to check from which user(account) this tab was opened to pull up the current user's cookies on a new tab.

Comment: Can I use `chrome.tabs.query` not only in popup.js but in background.js? or this is a foolish idea?

Comment: Maybe I need a content-script.js to handle clicks and new tabs from my main tab?